# Error upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 but do-release upgrade fails. In apt.log there are many Broken packages. But I'm scared to delete them all. I don't know which of them a needed.

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 6
 Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 6
 Investigating (0) systemd-sysv [ amd64 ] < 229-4ubuntu21.15 -> 237-3ubuntu10.11 > ( admin )
 Broken systemd-sysv:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-shim [ amd64 ] < 9-1bzr4ubuntu1 > ( admin )
   Considering systemd-shim:amd64 2 as a solution to systemd-sysv:amd64 117
   Added systemd-shim:amd64 to the remove list
   Fixing systemd-sysv:amd64 via remove of systemd-shim:amd64
   MarkDelete systemd-shim [ amd64 ] < 9-1bzr4ubuntu1 > ( admin ) FU=0
 Investigating (0) libcurl3 [ amd64 ] < 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.11 -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs )
 Broken libcurl3:amd64 Conflicts on libcurl4 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.5 > ( libs )
   Considering libcurl4:amd64 -1 as a solution to libcurl3:amd64 2
   Added libcurl4:amd64 to the remove list
   Conflicts//Breaks against version 7.58.0-2ubuntu3 for libcurl4 but that is not InstVer, ignoring
   Fixing libcurl3:amd64 via keep of libcurl4:amd64
   MarkKeep libcurl4 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.5 > ( libs ) FU=0
 Investigating (0) libglib2.0-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libglib2.0-dev:amd64 Depends on libpcre3-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 2:8.39-9 > ( libdevel ) (>= 1:8.31)
   Considering libpcre3-dev:amd64 0 as a solution to libglib2.0-dev:amd64 0
   MarkKeep libglib2.0-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libglib2.0-dev:amd64 rather than change libpcre3-dev:amd64
 Investigating (0) curl [ amd64 ] < 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.11 -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.5 > ( web )
 Broken curl:amd64 Depends on libcurl4 [ amd64 ] < none -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.5 > ( libs ) (= 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.5)
   Considering libcurl4:amd64 -1 as a solution to curl:amd64 0
   MarkKeep curl [ amd64 ] < 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.11 -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.5 > ( web ) FU=0
   Removing curl:amd64 rather than change libcurl4:amd64
   MarkDelete curl [ amd64 ] < 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.11 -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.5 > ( web ) FU=0
 Investigating (0) libharfbuzz-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.7.2-1ubuntu1 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 Depends on libglib2.0-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 2.56.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 > ( libdevel ) (>= 2.19.1)
   Considering libglib2.0-dev:amd64 0 as a solution to libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 0
   MarkKeep libharfbuzz-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.7.2-1ubuntu1 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 rather than change libglib2.0-dev:amd64
 Investigating (0) perl-modules-5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 > ( perl )
 Broken perl-modules-5.22:amd64 Conflicts on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < none ->  | 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.7 > ( perl )
   Conflicts//Breaks against version 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.7 for perl-modules but that is not InstVer, ignoring
   Considering perl-modules-5.26:amd64 44 as a solution to perl-modules-5.22:amd64 -1
   Removing perl-modules-5.22:amd64 rather than change perl-modules:amd64
   MarkDelete perl-modules-5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 > ( perl ) FU=0
 Investigating (0) libperl5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 > ( libs )
 Broken libperl5.22:amd64 Depends on perl-modules-5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 > ( perl ) (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6)
   Considering perl-modules-5.22:amd64 -1 as a solution to libperl5.22:amd64 -2
   Removing libperl5.22:amd64 rather than change perl-modules-5.22:amd64
   MarkDelete libperl5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 > ( libs ) FU=0
 Investigating (1) libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 Depends on libharfbuzz-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.7.2-1ubuntu1 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 0 as a solution to libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 rather than change libharfbuzz-dev:amd64
 Investigating (1) libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-dev:amd64 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libicu-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-dev:amd64 rather than change libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
 Investigating (2) icu-devtools [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3)
   Considering libicu-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to icu-devtools:amd64 3
   Upgrading libicu-dev:amd64 due to Breaks field in icu-devtools:amd64
 Investigating (2) libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-dev:amd64 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libicu-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-dev:amd64 rather than change libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
 Investigating (3) icu-devtools [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3)
   Considering libicu-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to icu-devtools:amd64 3
   Upgrading libicu-dev:amd64 due to Breaks field in icu-devtools:amd64
 Investigating (3) libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-dev:amd64 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libicu-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-dev:amd64 rather than change libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
 Investigating (4) icu-devtools [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3)
   Considering libicu-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to icu-devtools:amd64 3
   Upgrading libicu-dev:amd64 due to Breaks field in icu-devtools:amd64
 Investigating (4) libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-dev:amd64 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libicu-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-dev:amd64 rather than change libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
 Investigating (5) icu-devtools [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3)
   Considering libicu-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to icu-devtools:amd64 3
   Upgrading libicu-dev:amd64 due to Breaks field in icu-devtools:amd64
 Investigating (5) libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-dev:amd64 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libicu-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-dev:amd64 rather than change libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
 Investigating (6) icu-devtools [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3)
   Considering libicu-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to icu-devtools:amd64 3
   Upgrading libicu-dev:amd64 due to Breaks field in icu-devtools:amd64
 Investigating (6) libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-dev:amd64 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libicu-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-dev:amd64 rather than change libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
 Investigating (7) icu-devtools [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3)
   Considering libicu-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to icu-devtools:amd64 3
   Upgrading libicu-dev:amd64 due to Breaks field in icu-devtools:amd64
 Investigating (7) libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-dev:amd64 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libicu-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-dev:amd64 rather than change libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
 Investigating (8) icu-devtools [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3)
   Considering libicu-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to icu-devtools:amd64 3
   Upgrading libicu-dev:amd64 due to Breaks field in icu-devtools:amd64
 Investigating (8) libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-dev:amd64 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libicu-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-dev:amd64 rather than change libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
 Investigating (9) icu-devtools [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken icu-devtools:amd64 Breaks on libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) (< 60.2-3ubuntu3)
   Considering libicu-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to icu-devtools:amd64 3
   Upgrading libicu-dev:amd64 due to Breaks field in icu-devtools:amd64
 Investigating (9) libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel )
 Broken libicu-dev:amd64 Depends on libicu-le-hb-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.3+git161113-4 > ( libdevel )
   Considering libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libicu-dev:amd64 2
   MarkKeep libicu-dev [ amd64 ] < 55.1-7ubuntu0.4 -> 60.2-3ubuntu3 > ( libdevel ) FU=0
   Holding Back libicu-dev:amd64 rather than change libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
```

**sources.list**

```
#######################################################################################
# Hetzner APT-Mirror
#
# deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to xenial
# deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to xenial
# deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to xenial
# deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/security trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to xenial

#deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial           main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates   main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-security  main restricted universe multiverse

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
```

**sources.list.d/mosquitto-dev-mosquitto-ppa-trusty.list**

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa/ubuntu xenial main # disabled on upgrade to xenial
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

**sources.list.d/ondrej-php-trusty.list**

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial main # disabled on upgrade to xenial
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: "Broken packages" does NOT mean corrupt-and-should-be-deleted. It DOES mean that the *chain of dependencies* has been broken, usually by PPAs or other non-Ubuntu software. Merely commenting out the source is not enough. You must UNINSTALL all packages provided by those non-Ubuntu sources and return your system to close to stock condition as possible. Then do-release-upgrade will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

Removed the PPA's with following command.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:whatever/ppa
```

After that the do-release-upgrade finished with no errors.

Thank you to @s1mmel and @user535733 for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are broken packages. These broken dependencies need to be fixed first. Before you do a release upgrade, try the following.

Do

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

so that you have the latest packages available on your system. This should always be done prior to a version upgrade.

If you encounter dependency errors you could try to get rid of them, via

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

and/or

```
sudo dpkg –configure -a
```

and/or

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If it still does not work, try this

delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

After you upgraded to the last packages and the broken packages are fixed, you should be able to do a clean release upgrade with no problems.

Comment: Tried all your suggestions. Unfortunately without success. All packages are up-to-date. Apt-get showed no dependency errors. Deleting lock files didn't help too.

Comment: please post your repos, these are listed under /etc/apt/sources.list and als in the files located under /et/apt/sources.list.d/*

Comment: try to do the update without source code first, comment all deb-src entries, so they are not used yet. Same with the ppa, upgrade them AFTER you updated the main system. Are you doing development on this server, are you using the source code from the libs?

Comment: this is the culprit it seems: Broken systemd-sysv:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-shim [ amd64 ]. Question is, why is it broken. I'll try to further investigate and help you on this.